# How to replace substring with another substring (by index from..to)

Tags: ruby, string

How I can replace substring from some character to another by other string?

```
first = 4
last = 11
replacement = '...'
'show me the money'.replace_part(first, last, replacement)
# => 'show...money'
```

Comment: Could there be a better version of title? In its current form it's not very findable, I'm afraid. But I don't have any alternatives. :/

Comment: I know but I also can't come up with better :(

Comment: Maybe: "How to replace a substring with another substring"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
str = 'show me the money'
first = 4
last = 11
replacement = '...'
str[first..last] = replacement
str 
#=> 'show...money'
```