# Replace several substrings by indices at once in ruby

Tags: ruby

It's a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732125/how-to-replace-substring-with-another-substring-by-index-from-to), i.e. given a start and end index of a substring, replace it with another string, but I'd like to replace several substrings using indices. I can't just chain replacements since the indices refer to the original string. So I ended up counting chars, but there must be a better way.

```
res = original_string
delta = 0
# to keep things simple, assume replacements just contains objects which have start, end indices and replacements
replacements.each do |r|
  old_str = original_str[r.start_offset .. r.end_offset]
  new_str = r.replacement
  res[r.start_offset + delta .. r.end_offset + delta] = new_str
  delta += new_str.size - old_str.size
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just start replacing from the end. Then the indexes are always valid:

```
# to keep things simple, assume replacements just contains 
# objects which have start, end indices and replacements
replacements.sort_by(&:start_offset).reverse.each do |r|
  string[r.start_offset..r.end_offset] = r.replacement      
end
```